# How to pass input value to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have **form** with **input** and **submit button**. I would like to open popup while user fills e-mail address and click submit button. In popup will be other button which clicked should make action from the submit button with input value. I have something like this so far:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //function opening popup goes here... 

    // confirm button in popup
    $('#confirm_button').on('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    });
});
```

The problem is that I have no idea, how to pass value from the input to the confirming function in popup.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: into your popup function, you can console log thi: `$(this).find('#your_input'').val()` to see if you get the value of your input or not

Comment: what is ur html? i dont see a reason why u need to wrap ur click button with form submit since u already preventdefault at both of it

Comment: just use this to get input value `var val = $('#input').val()`

Comment: I would like to send form while user clicks on button in popup with value he filled before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a single value from a form, example of af an input element in html with id attribute set to **username**:

```
var userName = $('#username').val();
```

or to get all elements of a form where its id attribute is set to **myform**:

```
$("#myform").serialize()
```

To pass input value to other function you must first create a function:

```
function doSomething(first) {
    if (first) {
        console.log(first);
        alert(first);
    }
}

$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //function opening popup goes here...
});

// confirm button in popup
$('#confirm_button').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userName = $('#username').val();
    $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    doSomething(userName);
});
```

Note that the important part here is to use #id for accessing values in you page, this is how you access it with popup or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the information in a variable or mutliple, for example:

```
var name;
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get name from input and store it in the name variable.
    name = $('#name').val();
    //function opening popup goes here... 

    // confirm button in popup
    $('#confirm_button').on('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    });
});
```

You could then use name anywhere else in the JS

Comment: Thanks, got it. But how to make that user clicks button in popup and after that first submit button will be clicked and form send with value previously filled by user?

Comment: @JohnVanh You could make some hidden fields in the pop-up form and store the data from the other form in there. This way the pop-up form also has the other values